# SDL_Rect declaration with values not working

Tags: c, sdl, declaration, sdl-2, rect

I'm studying a code that contains:

```
...
SDL_Rect rect(0, 0, 100, 50);
...
```

But when I do it, i get the following error:

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
   49 |   SDL_Rect rect(0, 0, 100, 50);
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Is the code you're looking at C (as suggested by the tag) or C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're compiling as C, this is invalid. There are no constructors in C. The compiler is interpreting the first part of your code as a forward declaration, and the latter part confuses it.

Just define the SDL_Rect as such

```
SDL_Rect rect;

rect.x = 0;
rect.y = 0;
rect.w = 100;
rect.h = 50;
```

Here is the libsdl reference:
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Rect

Although since you're studying code, you probably want to just compile this as C++ as it appears that is what it was written in.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. But no, I'm willing to learn C and not C++.